# How can I change the mapped field name of an entry in a dictionary to be indexed by Elasticsearch via NEST?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I need to index some dynamic data (the fields are not known at compile time) and I also need to index a GeoPoint.

I want to use the NEST api and index into Elasticsearch. I have the following code to handle this:

```
public class MyRow
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Name = "GeometryHotspot", Type = FieldType.GeoPoint)]
    public Coordinate GeometryHotspot { get; set; }    

    public Dictionary<string, object> DynamicValues { get; set; }
}
```

This works, but when I setup the dynamic values in the array like this:

```
row.DynamicValues["MyKey"] = "Some value";
```

Then Elasticsearch generates a Lucene field named "DynamicValues.MyKey" for this value. Due to some legacy issues (existing queries in the field), I need the Lucene field to be "MyKey" - and not prefixed with "DynamicValues."

Does anybody know how this can be achieved? I have looked at various mapping approaches, but no luck. I cannot figure out how to specify the Lucene field name - only whether it should be analyzed etc. I

Comment: What about the case where the Dictionary contains a key value that matches the name of a property on `MyRow`?

Comment: That scenario is avoided by use of prefixes on the keys themselves. All dynamic keys in the dictionary have a prefix on their own, i.e. "MyCompany.MyUniqueKey" (the legacy system already enforces this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a round about way to achieve what you want. Add the `Id` and `GeometryHotspot` key-values to `DynamicValues` dictionary and then index `DynamicValues` instead of `MyRow` object. You can use the power of [`dynamic templates`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html) here to achieve the mapping you desire. I've written a small program to illustrate this.

```
public class Coordinate
{
    public float lat { get; set; }
    public float lon { get; set; }
}

public class MyRow
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Coordinate GeometryHotspot { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> DynamicValues { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var row = new MyRow
        {
            Id = "randomid",
            GeometryHotspot = new Coordinate
            {
                lat = 1.23f,
                lon = 4.56f
            },
            DynamicValues = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                ["numberField"] = 1,
                ["stringField"] = "TWO",
                ["dateField"] = DateTime.UtcNow,
                ["realNumberField"] = 25.6,
                ["booleanField"] = true
            }
        };

        // Add the concrete fields of MyRow class to its DynamicValues property
        row.DynamicValues["id"] = row.Id;
        row.DynamicValues["geometryHotspot"] = row.GeometryHotspot;

        var client = new ElasticClient(new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200")));

        // Create a mapping called "myRow" in index "myindex". Make sure "myindex" exists already.
        client.Map<object>(d => d
            .Index("myindex")
            .Type("myRow")
            .DynamicTemplates(dtd => dtd
                .Add(dd => dd
                    .Name("geopoint")
                    .Match("geometryHotspot")
                    .Mapping(fm => fm
                        .GeoPoint(f => f
                            .IndexLatLon())))));

        client.Index(row.DynamicValues, d => d  // Notice how we index row.DynamicValues and not row
            .Index("myindex")
            .Type("myRow"));
    }
}
```

After this, simply search for all documents in "myindex" index and "myRow" type to see that the dynamic fields are no longer prefixed by "DynamicFields." string.

Below is the output of the `_search` API.

```
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "myindex",
            "_type": "myRow",
            "_id": "AVIqRf4rqbcnf7z9goAa",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "numberField": 1,
               "stringField": "TWO",
               "dateField": "2016-01-10T06:42:55.7535106Z",
               "realNumberField": 25.6,
               "booleanField": true,
               "id": "randomid",
               "geometryHotspot": {
                  "lat": 1.23,
                  "lon": 4.56
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I was  hoping there was a way to combine the two approaches for simplicity (since we also have a static schema), but I guess not. This is helpful though - thanks!